# Formatting int to currency-formatted string in aspx page

Tags: asp.net

Suppose I have this label in my aspx page:

```
<asp:Label ID="savings" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("savings")%>' />
```

Is there a way to format the text of a label as a currency-formatted string? I'm looking for something like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="savings" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("savings").ToString("C")%>' />
```

When I run this I get the:

```
 No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments
```

compilation error.

I know I can easily do this in my code-behind but I want to know if it's possible from the .aspx document.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<asp:Label ID="savings" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("savings"))%>' />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code if you are dealing with string

```
<asp:Label ID="savings" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:c}", Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("savings")))%>' />
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ToString(string)` method only operates on numerical types, but `Eval(string)` returns `object`.

Cast the result to the correct type before calling the extension method on it, like this:

`<%# ((decimal)Eval("savings")).ToString("C") %>`

Answer (score 0):

Late.. but useful

Anyone looking for Indian Currency Format or any other Currency use the CultureInfo class.
example:

```
(YourData).ToString("C2",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("in-IN"));
```

i would recommend that you convert the data you are trying to format to decimal in order to skip any overheads, also check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) page for more culture combinations and more about formatting.